# In nextjs 13, Auto changes doesn't update in browser

Tags: reactjs, frontend, next.js13

I have installed the very new **Nextjs 13** application on my **Windows 11** machine.

When I make any changes in the code editor (Vscode). It doesn't reflect in the browser (all browsers), even when I manually refresh the browser.

I have started the local server (*http://localhost:3000/*) using `npm run dev`

In *package.json* file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.6.3",
    "@types/react": "18.2.22",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.16",
    "eslint": "8.49.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.5.2",
    "next": "13.5.2",
    "postcss": "8.4.30",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
    "typescript": "5.2.2"
  }
```

**Note:**
Versions:
**node** - *v18.16.0* |
**npm** - *9.5.1*

**How to rectify the issue! (Auto update issue in browser).**

Comment: Sounds like you need t open an issue in [Nextjs repository](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues)

Comment: can you share your code or repo.

Comment: try LTS version of Node : https://nodejs.org/en/download/current

Answer (score 2):

I think auto save mode is disabled in your vscode and file does not save. use ctrl + s  to save file .

Comment: I have manually saved the file using the ctrl + s. Still facing the issue

Comment: I had same issue initially. I deleted ``.next`` folder and run ``npm run dev`` command again. It's working fine now. (Not sure why it was not working before and why its working again)

Comment: This answer saved me!!! somehow my synced settings changed and the autosave setting as well and so I am just scratching my head for hours why my changes were not reflecting. smh